# Angular slider for a video player with support in IE8 - with JW player plugin

Tags: angularjs, jwplayer, uislider

I am using a JW Player plugin to play a video and customizing the skin to make it more compatible in IE 8 browser. But I need to help to implement slider funtionality in seek bar which needs to support in IE8.

How to do slider functionality in seek bar for IE8 in AngularJS? Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain JavaScript, using the JW Player API:

```
 <input type="range" id="myRange" value="60">
 <script>
    var playerInstance = jwplayer('playerDiv');
    playerInstance.on('time', function(x) {
        var playPos = x.position;
        document.getElementById("myRange").value(playPos);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you succeeded in getting JW6 or 7 to play on IE8 without Angular? The slider components are `<input type='range'/>`.Take a look here at [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-range). IE9 isn't even capable of using range inputs.

Comment: Yes bro, I have succeeded in getting JW6 to play on IE8 without Angular. Btw input range is not supported in IE8 and IE9. I guess its a wonderful share. Thank you please share your thoughts here.

I will post the Answer if I get one.